# swap two lines script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file structured as follow:

```
 msgid ""
    msgstr ""
    "PO-Revision-Date: 2013-04-08 10:12:14+0000\n"
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
    "Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n > 1;\n"
    "X-Generator: GlotPress/0.1\n"
    "Project-Id-Version: Modern Theme\n"

    #: 404.php:34
    msgid "Page not found"
    msgstr "Page non trouvée"

    #: alert-form.php:6
    msgid "You have sucessfully subscribed to the alert"
    msgstr "Vous vous êtes inscrit avec succès à cette alerte"

    #: alert-form.php:7 user-change_email.php:42
    msgid "Invalid email address"
    msgstr "Adresse e-mail incorrecte"

    #: alert-form.php:8
    msgid "There was a problem with the alert"
    msgstr "Il y a un problème avec cette alerte"

    #: alert-form.php:39
    msgid "Subscribe to this search"
    msgstr "Abonnez vous à cette recherche"

    #: alert-form.php:55
    msgid "Subscribe now"
    msgstr "Abonnez-vous maintenant"

    #: contact.php:35
    msgid "Contact us"
    msgstr "Contactez-nous"
```

I would like to swap the content, of the line than contain the string msgid, between the brackets with the content, on the successive line that contain msgstr, between the brackets, can you please give me hint to write script or do it through command line ?

Comment: why don't you just swap `msgid` with `msgstr` or do you have to preserve their position relatively?

Comment: Yes so for ex:  
 msgid "Page not found"
 msgstr "Page non trouvée"
become : 
 msgid "Page non trouvée"
 msgstr "Page not found"

Comment: That is the same thing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` and `sed` to do this. Following works.

```
awk '/msg.*/{getline x;print x;}1' file | sed -e 's/msgid/msgidt/g' -e 's/msgstr/msgid/g' -e 's/msgidt/msgstr/g'
```

`awk` swaps the lines that matches with the regex `msg.*` and pipe it to `sed`. First `sed` renames `msgid` to a temporary one `msgidt` and then renames `msgstr` to `msgid` and finally `msgidt` to `msgid`.

Result :

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"PO-Revision-Date: 2013-04-08 10:12:14+0000\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n > 1;\n"
"X-Generator: GlotPress/0.1\n"
"Project-Id-Version: Modern Theme\n"

#: 404.php:34
msgid "Page non trouvee"
msgstr "Page not found"

#: alert-form.php:6
msgid "Vous vous Cetes inscrit avec succsess  cette alerte"
msgstr "You have sucessfully subscribed to the alert"

#: alert-form.php:7 user-change_email.php:42
msgid "Adresse e-mail incorrecte"
msgstr "Invalid email address"

#: alert-form.php:8
msgid "Il y a un problC(me avec cette alerte"
msgstr "There was a problem with the alert"

#: alert-form.php:39
msgid "Abonnez vous C  cette recherche"
msgstr "Subscribe to this search"

#: alert-form.php:55
msgid "Abonnez-vous maintenant"
msgstr "Subscribe now"

#: contact.php:35
msgid "Contactez-nous"
msgstr "Contact us"
```

Comment: Thanks I need to save the output on file with iso-8859-1
I tried > file  but it was saved on UTF-8 ?

Comment: You can use `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 in.txt > out.txt`